# Wordpress: add new strings (and translate them) on child theme

Tags: wordpress

I have a parent theme and I did create a child theme.
I did put a folder inside child theme `/lang` that overwrite parent and all went done. I did have my theme translate in italian and english.

Now I need to add a field to the registration form, so I use this code:

```
function tre_custom_woocommerce_register_form () {



    ?>



    <p><label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox inline">

        <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox" name="privacy_mandatary" type="checkbox" id="privacy_mandatary" /> <span><a href="/shop/policy-privacy"><?php _e('Autorizzo il trattamento dei miei dati, come riportato alla lett. A punti 1, 2 e 3 della policy privacy', 'mychildtheme-child'); ?></a></span>

    </label></p>
```

So basically I did "create" another language domain (`mychildtheme-child`) different from parent.

In functions.php I did use this snippet:

```
function mychild_load_languages() {

    load_child_theme_textdomain( 'mychildtheme-child', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mychild_load_languages' );
```

And in the new folder called `/languages/` (different from the other) I did put my .pot and the translations. But translates are not called, I have the theme only italian.

So, summarizing:

I have the parent theme with folder `lang` (it works)
I have the child with folder `lang` (it works). When I swith to English, I got all text translated (but not the new)
I have the child with folder `languages` (together with previous point) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [`load_child_theme_textdomain`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_child_theme_textdomain/), you need to also make sure you have a `.mo` file in your child themes root directory as well. Then you also need to ensure you have `.po` and `.pot` language files present in your language folder.

Also, you need to use the same text domain as the parent theme and not create a new text domain for your child theme. According to [this comment in the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_child_theme_textdomain/#comment-1552), whilst the translations can be in your child theme, it needs to imitate the parent theme as it's treated as one theme.

***Excerpt from that comment:***

> ```
> function wpdocs_child_theme_setup() {
>     load_child_theme_textdomain( 'my_parent_theme', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
> }
> add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpdocs_child_theme_setup' );
> ```
>
> ‘my_parent_theme’ = The name of the Main theme
>
> The .mo files must use language-only filenames, like languages/de_DE.mo in your child theme directory.

For compatibility, make sure the languages folder is called the same as the parent themes language folder (*`/lang` in your case*) and the `.mo`, `.po` and `.pot` files are in a valid format.